# How to verify text on a page using Keywords?

Tags: katalon-studio

I am trying to verify some text on a page which appears after a spinner finishes loading. Is it possible to perform this type of test in Katalon?

I tried creating a Keyword and then using it but have no idea what to do next.

```
public class ModuleKeywords {


    @Keyword
    def myText(String){
    myText = WebUI.getText(findTestObject('Object Repository/WMS/Page_/li_System Activity'))
    return myText
    }

}
```

```
def sysText = CustomKeywords.'com.wms.modules.general.ModuleKeywords.myText'()

    if (sysText == 'System Activity') {

    println("The text displayed is = "  + sysText)

}
    else
    println('Activity page did not load')
```

I expect the code to find and verify the text "System Activity" on the page after a link is clicked and the spinner is done loading.

I get the following error after running the script:
2019-09-10 13:52:42.921 ERROR k.k.c.m.CustomKeywordDelegatingMetaClass - ❌ No such property: myText for class: com.wms.modules.general.ModuleKeywords
2019-09-10 13:52:42.925 ERROR c.k.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor   - ❌ Test Cases/regression/WMS/C16320 - Activity Module FAILED.
Reason:
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: myText for class: com.wms.modules.general.ModuleKeywords
    at com.wms.modules.general.ModuleKeywords.myText(ModuleKeywords.groovy:26)
    at com.wms.modules.general.ModuleKeywords.invokeMethod(ModuleKeywords.groovy)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.CustomKeywordDelegatingMetaClass.invokeStaticMethod(CustomKeywordDelegatingMetaClass.java:50)
    at C16320 - Activity Module.run(C16320 - Activity Module:23)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.ScriptEngine.run(ScriptEngine.java:194)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.ScriptEngine.runScriptAsRawText(ScriptEngine.java:119)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.runScript(TestCaseExecutor.java:337)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.doExecute(TestCaseExecutor.java:328)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.processExecutionPhase(TestCaseExecutor.java:307)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.accessMainPhase(TestCaseExecutor.java:299)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.execute(TestCaseExecutor.java:233)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseMain.runTestCase(TestCaseMain.java:114)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseMain$runTestCase$0.call(Unknown Source)
    at TempTestCase1568141525512.run(TempTestCase1568141525512.groovy:21)

Comment: Do you use something like "waitForElementPresent" BuiltInKeywords for your script? if not better to use it.

Comment: By Keywords, I meant Custom Keywords and not BuiltInKeywords.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some confusion on what `myText` means. It is unclear if it is a method name or a property name.

So, I suggest you change the name of the text variable (I'll name it just `text`) inside of your method. Be sure to add the `def` keyword, as well.

Finally, when writing a method with this signature `def myText(String)` you are saying the method accepts a string parameter, but you are not providing the parameter in your example so it is not needed.

Your method will then look like this:

```
@Keyword
def myText(){
    def text = WebUI.getText(findTestObject('Object Repository/WMS/Page_/li_System Activity'))
    return text
}
```

Comment: Yes, myText was a variable to store the text which I wanted to verify. Is it ok to use the same variable name as the method name or it should be different? Can I use String text instead of def text?

Comment: I tried with this and it worked, otherwise I would get the same error as you. You can use String text, sure.